# CSS animation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have just started to learn JavaScript and am trying to make an analog clock. First I have created the second meter with css. Then I am trying to convert it into JavaScript. I don't want to use any jQuery or any other JS framework for this.

How to set the css @keyframe in JavaScript? Here is my code for CSS:

```
.second{
  height: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition: rotate(360deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

js code for this css

```
var second = document.querySelector(".second");
      second.style.height = "5px";
      second.style.width = "180px";
      second.style.backgroundColor = "#aaaaaa";
      second.style.borderRadius = "5px";
      second.style.position = "absolute";
      second.style.top = "50%";
      second.style.left = "50%";
      second.style.transformOrigin = "left center";
      second.style.zIndex = "3";

      second.style.webkitAnimationName = "Spin";
      second.style.webkitAnimationDuration = "60s";
      second.style.webkitAnimationIterationCount: "infinite"; //doesn't work
      second.style.webkitAnimationTimingFunction: "linear"; //doesn't work
      second.style.oTransition: "rotate(360deg)"; //doesn't work
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Javascript for this? This can be done in css alone.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj maybe OP can do it in css, just want to learn javascript.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj You may to look at the requestAnimationFrame() function - see the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Does what you've written work, and if not, how does it not work?

Comment: @DavidVotrubec It seems that he wants (for some unknown reason) to set the styles programmatically, while continuing to use CSS animations, in which case there is no need for `rAF`.

Comment: There's three answers below that came in on the day that you posted your question. It's technically not mandatory to reply to people or vote, but it is certainly polite to respond in some fashion. Would you consider doing so now?

Answer (score 1):

This can be trivially achieved by appending the desired text (the @keyframes spin rule) to a style tag in the document.I haven't bothered to do a check to see if it's been done yet, so clicking the button multiple times will append the rule multiple times. It needs at least 1 style tag to function, the tag used is the last one and lastly, this will fail if the last style tag references an external file.

To trivially avoid these limitations, you can simply create a new script element and append it to the `document.head` element. You'll just want to set a flag or give the tag a class so you can find it later and avoid adding it twice.

```js
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}

function onStart()
{
 var styleTags = allByTag('style');
 var lastStyleElem = styleTags[ styleTags.length-1 ];
 
 var txt = '@keyframes spin {' + '\n';
  txt += ' from {transform:rotate(0deg);}' + '\n';
  txt += ' to {transform:rotate(360deg);}' + '\n';
  txt += '}' + '\n';
 lastStyleElem.innerHTML += txt;
}
```

```css
.second{
  height: 5px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition: rotate(360deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='onStart()'>Start transform</button>
<div class='second'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why this would be done in JavaScript although there might be. I guess if your trying to learn JavaScript learning real world practices might be better. But if you must I suppose you can add it to the head element like so.

```
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.type = 'text/css';
var props = 
'@-webkit-keyframes spin {' +
  'from {' +
    '-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);' +
            'transform: rotate(0deg); }' +
  'to {' +
    '-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);' +
            'transform: rotate(360deg); } }' +
'@keyframes spin {' +
  'from {' +
    '-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);' +
            'transform: rotate(0deg); }' +
  'to {' +
    '-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);' +
            'transform: rotate(360deg); } }';
styleElement.appendChild(props);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

MDN is a great resource, with animation you can declare a lot on one line rather then breaking it up on 5 lines etc

`animation: spin 60s infinite linear;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Not sure how you are going to create keyframes in vanilla javascript, but if they are declared in css "spin" will apply the keyframes.

PS if you want to learn Vanilla JavaScript start with a calculator.